# In the cpanel bandwidth report is it possible to change the colors of the graphs? the Red color

Tags: cpanel, bandwidth

Is it possible to customize the graph colors in the cPanel bandwidth report, specifically the red one?

I need to know if cpanel has any way to customize the colors of the graphics

there is no customization menu.

I am in a legal pot and one of the evidence is the report.  but every month the main domain is red and the month where the error occurs, the main domain is blue.  as if it were.modified.

I thank you in advance if you can help me.

Comment: I think this question better suits [other SE site](https://superuser.com/). Please read description of the _cpanel_ tag.